# Can i use sysdate for setting permissions in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, permissions, sysdate

Is there any way to put permission for a specific range of hours using the `SYSDATE` in a sql command?

Comment: Can you talk more about why you need this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a product which does this: Database Vault.  It allows us to specify policies which govern access and privileges for *all* database users (including DBAs), on a timed basis.  Proper enforcement of such policies requires that the administrators are not part of that community of database users.

The bad news is that this product is a chargeable extra to the Enterprise Edition licence.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/database-vault/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Virtual Private Database to apply a policy to a table to make it only readable during select hours.